# How to specify pip extra-index-url when creating an azureml environment?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When AzureML creates a python environment and runs `pip install`, I'd like it to use additional non-public indices. Is there a way to do that?

I'm running my python script on an AzureML compute. The environment is created from pip requirements as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-use-environments#conda-and-pip-specification-files). The script now references a package in a private index. To run the script on a local or build machine I just specify `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable with credentials to the index before running `pip install -c ...`. How to enable same functionality on AzureML environment prep process?

AzureML docs [suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-use-environments#private-wheel-files) that I directly supply wheel files instead of package names. That means I have to manually do all the work that pip is built for: identify private packages among other requirements, choose right versions and platform, download them.

Ideally, I would have to just write something like this:

```
myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(
    name = "myenv",
    file_path = "path-to-pip-requirements-file",
    extra-index-url = ["url1", "url2"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, there is a [`set_pip_option` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.conda_dependencies.condadependencies?view=azure-ml-py#set-pip-option-pip-option-) in the SDK which sorts out the problem with one single extra-index-url, e.g.

```py
from azureml.core.environment import CondaDependencies
dep = CondaDependencies.create(pip_packages=["pyyaml", "param"])
dep.set_pip_option("--extra-index-url https://user:password@extra.index/url")
```

Unfortunately, second call to this function replaces the first value with the new one. For the `--extra-index-url` option this logic should be changed in order to support search in more than 2 indices (one public, one private).

Comment: please note that you can pass a list to --extra-index-url, like so:

`dep.set_pip_option("--extra-index-url https://user:password@extra.index/url1,https://user:password@extra.index/url2")`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Pip (as of v19.3.1) treats differently this option when it comes from cmdline/requirements vs. when it comes from config/env. In a config file or a PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL you can supply a space-delimited list of urls. On a cmdline or a requirements file each option is a single value which is appended to the list of extra urls. In particular, pip will treat the above example as ONE extra url with comma in the middle and, obviously, fail.

Comment: and this username password is your azure devops username & personal Access Tokens.

Answer (score 3):

if you have your requirements file you can have extra index urls specified there
re.txt

--extra-index-url foo
--extra-index-url bar
package_a
package_b
package_x

for more options please check here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

the same is with yaml files

Comment: Thank you, although this solution may end up in credentials being checked in to a repository which is a bad practice.

Comment: I see, you can try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.environment?view=azure-ml-py#add-private-pip-wheel-workspace--file-path--exist-ok-false-